# Make Threads Per List Item

Tags: java

I am new to Java Concurrency and not really comfortable with examples provided by the docs.
What i am trying to do is, I have a database of employers which i retrieve their credentials from the database and store it in java.util.list. I want to perform independent actions of each employee stored in the list concurrently. Is Multi-Threading the right direction ? and could i be guided with some pseudo example ?

N:B If my question is vague, comment so i may improve it rather than downvote.It's important i understand how i could accomplish this. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need multiple threads? Do you have a performance issue?

Comment: @assylias each employee has a certain task to accomplish from a particular start time to an end time. I am trying to simulate a system whereby i have a group of independent actions to run on. So there is a chance that multiple employees are executing at the same time and finish at different times.

Comment: That sounds very strange to me. Is this a kind of project planning ? don't you know the duration of the tasks beforehand ? what kind of interactions do you want to test with concurrency ?

Comment: @perencia, let me give an example. I developed a distributed printing application where employees of a company could print their stuff. There are many printers thus there could be many printing jobs at different moments at different time intervals. Now, i am trying to do a test process whereby, i have a long list of employees,the time they started printing, the time they stopped printing and the printer they used. I want to run this list of actions on the project.

Comment: Ok, just to clarify, the duration of the printing tasks would be random then ?

Comment: In that case, perhaps it'd be more useful to use something like DelayQueue and put the tasks in it? using threads for simulation like that seems quite a waste.

Comment: @MightyPork I agree.. it seems to me that the threads will do nothing just to run in parallel and give start and end times.. it's not necessary to use threads just for that, if that's the case..

Comment: @perencia the durations have already been predefined in the database

Comment: so, the threads have to do anything beside running in parallel ?

Comment: @perencia just running in parallel and terminating when the endtime is equal to present datetime.

Comment: sorry but I don't see the point, not just on using threads, but on the same requirement you express :) Is that just for graphical visualization ?

Comment: @perencia yes i could say for graphical visualisation. It's to test the system.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-threading, unless your task is very time consuming, is overkill. Especially if the list is large, making a thread for every single item is likely to be slower than just iterating over the list and doing it one-at-a-time.

More useful would be to divide the list into several chunks and process *those* in parallel.

Anyway, if you insist on using threads, you might make some use of [ExecutorService](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see my response to the comment beneath the question if it has some meaning and could change your view on the answer

Comment: Yes, ExecutorService could work very well for this kind of task (or rather, a simulation).